# Converting a date string which is before 1970 into a timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Not a very good title, so my apologies.

For some reason, (I wasn't the person who did it, i digress) we have a table structure where the field type for a date is varchar. (odd).

We have some dates, such as:

```
1932-04-01 00:00:00 and 1929-07-04 00:00:00
```

I need to do a query which will convert these date strings into a unix time stamp, however, in mySQL if you convert a date which is before 1970 it will return 0.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

EDIT: Wrong date format. ooops.

Comment: Also, if I convert a date before 1970 into a timestamp I should expect a negative value.

Comment: Why a unix timestamp ? I'd invest some time into figuring out if you can use something else than unix timestamps - as dealing with unix timestamps < 1970 in a big can of worm..

Comment: @nos - I agree with you entirely, however, alas, it's not my job to do that. It's one of those things where a colleague came running to me to ask if I could help him with a problem.

I have recommended changing it, but it's all down to him.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Aha! We've found a solution!

The SQL to do it:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( STR_TO_DATE('04-07-1988','%d-%m-%Y'),FROM_UNIXTIME(0))*24*3600 -> 583977600
SELECT DATEDIFF( STR_TO_DATE('04-07-1968','%d-%m-%Y'),FROM_UNIXTIME(0))*24*3600 -> -47174400
```

This could be useful for future reference.

You can test it here: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: Is this independent of server timezone?

Comment: This doesn't work correctly when the date might have been on a different GMT offset (such as if the date was on summer time or non-summer time). This is because when we have the concept of summer time a day is not always 24 hours, one day per year is 25 hours and another is 23 hours. If the previous date is an even number of clock changes ago then the resulting timestamp will be right, but when it is not then it will be out by an hour. We go around this by using PHP to do the conversion as couldn't find a sensible way in SQL alone.

Answer (score 4):

I've adapted the DATEDIFF workaround to also include time not just days.  I've wrapped it up into a stored function, but you can just extract the SELECT part out if you don't want to use functions.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION SIGNED_UNIX_TIMESTAMP (d DATETIME)
RETURNS BIGINT
 DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE tz VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE ts BIGINT;
    SET tz = @@time_zone;
    SET time_zone = '+00:00';
    SELECT DATEDIFF(d, FROM_UNIXTIME(0)) * 86400 +
    TIME_TO_SEC(
      TIMEDIFF(
        d,
        DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(YEAR(d), DAYOFYEAR(d)), INTERVAL 0 HOUR)
      )
    ) INTO ts;
    SET time_zone = tz;
    return ts;
  END|
DELIMITER ;

-- SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-02 03:45:00');
-- will return 0
-- SELECT SIGNED_UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-02 03:45:00');
-- will return -2208888900
```

Answer (score 2):

> convert these date strings into a
>   unix time stamp

Traditional Unix timestamps are an unsigned integer count of seconds since 1-Jan-1970 therefore can't represent any date before that.

Comment: It can if it returns a negative value.

PHP for example can understand a negative timestamp value and convert to a string...

Answer (score 2):

At best you will have mixed results depending on the system you are using to represent the timestamp.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

> There was originally some controversy
>   over whether the Unix time_t  should
>   be signed or unsigned. If unsigned,
>   its range in the future would be
>   doubled, postponing the 32-bit
>   overflow (by 68 years). However, it
>   would then be incapable of
>   representing times prior to 1970.
>   Dennis Ritchie, when asked about this
>   issue, said that he hadn't thought
>   very deeply about it, but was of the
>   opinion that the ability to represent
>   all times within his lifetime would be
>   nice. (Ritchie's birth, in 1941, is
>   around Unix time −893 400 000.) The
>   consensus is for time_t to be signed,
>   and this is the usual practice. The
>   software development platform for
>   version 6 of the QNX operating system
>   has an unsigned 32-bit time_t, though
>   older releases used a signed type.

It appears that MySQL treats timestamps as an unsigned integer, meaning that times before the Epoc will all resolve to 0.

This being the case, you always have the option to implement your own unsigned timestamp type and use that for your calculations.

Answer (score 2):

If its feasible for your problem, you could shift all your mysql times by, say 100 years, and then work with those adjusted timestamps or re calculate the negative timestamp value.

As some have said, make sure your system is using 64bits to represent the timestamp otherwise you'll hit the year 2038 problem.

Comment: I just read that and first thought, what a bloody good idea! :D

and then realise we're running on a 32bit system. :-(

I was doing a bit of googl'ing and apparently I can use date_add to get the interval of seconds between 1970 and a birthdate and then minus the interval from 1970. Hope that makes sense.

For example, I have this at the moment:

SELECT date_add('1970-01-01', interval t.testdate second) as testdate_timestamp FROM random.test t;

But alas, that is as far as i've got!

Comment: Don't confuse the 64bit with the hardware. Maybe your system can handle it, try it. Also, depending on your needs, you could use the database to do all your date related logic for you so you don't have to worry about it in PHP for example - in PHP you could just work with, say years.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried the above solutions but this might in case you are not able to retrieve the date value from the MySQL database in the form of timestamp, then this operation can also be tried

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,FROM_UNIXTIME(0),'1960-01-01 00:00:00');

Answer (score 0):

To get the max. Range +/- wise use this query on your birthday field, in my case "yyyy-mm-dd" but you can change it to your needs

```
select name, (@bday:=STR_TO_DATE(birthday,"%Y-%m-%d")),if(year(@bday)<1970,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(adddate(@bday, interval 68 year))-2145916800,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@bday)) from people
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like we're making this much too difficult...

Use my functions below so you can convert *anything* to and from unix timestamps, much like you do in a browser.

Call functions like this:

```
select to_unix_time('1776-07-04 10:02:00'),
from_unix_time(-6106024680000);
```

By compiling these:

```
delimiter $$
create function to_unix_time (
    p_datetime datetime
) returns bigint
deterministic
begin
    declare v_ret bigint;
    
    select round(timestampdiff(
        microsecond,
        '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
        p_datetime
    ) / 1000, 0)
    into v_ret;
    
    return v_ret;
end$$

create function from_unix_time (
    p_time bigint
) returns datetime(6)
deterministic
begin
    declare v_ret datetime(6);
    
    select '1970-01-01 00:00:00' +
    interval (p_time * 1000) microsecond
    into v_ret;
    
    return v_ret;
end$$
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Date instead of timestamps. Date will solve your Problems.
check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)