# Why does this break strtotime

Tags: php

I have this code below and it outputs
26/11/1949 but when run through the `strtotime` it outputs the `ephoc` time of 1970

```
$var = '26/11/1949';
echo $var;
$var = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($var));
echo $var;
```

More importantly how can I get the rearranged version of dates before and after ephoc?

Comment: What version of PHP, and what operating system? before PHP 5.1.0 the range for timestamps was limited from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems such as Windows

Comment: Why would that matter? It will be run on varying setups

Comment: I've just added the "why" it matters to my comment

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Is there a method that avoids this. I cannot change what version of PHP is run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that **strtotime()** can not recognize your date.

List of date formats acceptable by **strtotime()** are listed in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) . Unfortunately the format you use **dd/mm/y** doesn't match any format listed there. So if you keep using your code you'll have wrong data conversion in most cases.

My suggestion is to parse the date manually, use [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to get UNIX timestamp from it and then use date to output format date. Optionally you can start using different **strtotime()** friendly date format if your scripts allow it.

I'd also recomend using [DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class especially if you plan to do further manipulation with your date. The you can use [DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y')](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function to het DateTime object from your string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `26/11/1949` is not a date in a format that `strtotime()` recognizes. When the parts of a date are separated by `/`, it expects it to be `m/d/Y`, but `26` is not a valid month number.

You should use `Date::create_from_format` so you can specify how `$var` should be parsed:

```
$date = Date::create_from_format('d/m/Y', $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because:

The unix time stamp is a way to track time as a running total of seconds. This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC. Therefore, the unix time stamp is merely the number of seconds between a particular date and the Unix Epoch. It should also be pointed out (thanks to the comments from visitors to this site) that this point in time technically does not change no matter where you are located on the globe. This is very useful to computer systems for tracking and sorting dated information in dynamic and distributed applications both online and client side.

Source: http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. So how should i reformat the date?

Comment: I don't see what this answer has to do with the question.

Comment: @Max Just a simple google search will give you this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788571/converting-a-date-string-which-is-before-1970-into-a-timestamp-in-mysql

Comment: That's in MySQL though

Comment: I supposed you were using MySQL because thats most used with PHP and you didn't tag another database.

Comment: What does this have to do with databases at all?

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` returns the number of seconds since the epoch. However from the docs:

> Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, therefore
>   your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch. This
>   means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work on Windows,
>   some Linux distributions, and a few other operating systems. PHP 5.1.0
>   and newer versions overcome this limitation though

As an alternative if you know the format I would recommend creating a date from that format:

```
$var = '26/11/1949';
echo $var;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y');
$var = $date->format('d/m/Y');
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Date Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

if PHP sees a `/` in the string, it assumes US format dates `mm/dd/YYYY` and the 11th day of the 26th month isn't valid

UK format dates need `-` rather than `/`

```
$var = date("d/m/Y", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$var)));
```

But better to use DateTime objects anyway

Comment: This may work, but which of the following is the `11th of Oct, 1949` - `10-11-1949` or `11-10-1949`?

Comment: @Tigger `11-10-1949` would be the 11th of October.... OP is clearly using UK/European date format here; but the `/` separator tells PHP that it's US date format, `11th October` would be `10/11/1949` in US date format

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a date returned of 1/1/1970 is that `strtotime()` is failing and returning `false` which converts to `1/1/1970` the first unix epoch date.

These sort of problems all revolve around the fact that the Americans for some obsquire reason start a date with the month and then the day and then the year. Sound ok when you speak it but it makes date convertion a bit of a nightmare because computers, and the rest of the world, use a more logical y/m/d or d/m/y. So PHP assumes it is a Amerian date format if it see's a `/` in the date string.

So the date convertion would work if you were to use

```
$var = '11/26/1949';
echo $var . PHP_EOL;
$var = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($var));
echo $var;
```

But luckily it will also work if you convert the seperators to `-` instead of `/`

```
$var = '26/11/1949';
echo $var . PHP_EOL;
$var = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
echo 'Converted date ' . $var . PHP_EOL;
$var = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($var));
echo $var;
```