# A year to Unix Time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Having difficulties when converting a year to unix time in MySQL.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `born_date` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unix_born_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `death_date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unix_death_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In the field born_date I have years, like «1864». I want to convert them to Unix Time in a query, something like:

```
SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(born_date, '%Y')) AS Unixtime
FROM person
```

But it returns 0…

Does anyone has an idea what to do to convert the year to Unix Time?

N.

Comment: isn't `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(born_date)` working?

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())` works, but when I write `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(born_date, '%Y'))`, it returns a 0…

Comment: Born date isn't a valid date.  If you had  a day/month then you'd have a born date.  as it stands you have a Born Year, and year byitself is insufficient to convert to a unix time stamp... you could add Jan 1 as the month year and it should work. or keep it as a int instead of a date.  since you can only work with year.  Think about it a year is how many hours minutes/seconds... which one should unix timestamp use?  Maybe if you had week... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763340/how-to-convert-week-number-and-year-into-unix-timestamp

Comment: born_date I'd recommend changing to a DATETIME field too

Comment: There are seriously errors in your design. `born_date` should be date not int, unix_born_date should be timestamp not varchar, death_date should be date or datetime not varchar and unix_death_date should be timestamp. AND if you create the fields with appropriate type you wont need then duplicated as you have now.

Comment: You are in reason Jorge, I will make this changes in a moment…

Answer (score 0):

when you pass the date, the format need meeds to be YYYY-MM-DD

select id,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat(date_format(born_date,'%Y'),'-01-01')

Comment: `SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(born_date,'%Y'),'-01-01'))` returns a NULL, and `SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(born_date,'-01-01'),'%Y-%m-%d'))` returns a 0…

Comment: sorry , the format isn't what i thought , try UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(born_date, '%Y'),'-01-01'))

Comment: `SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(born_date,'-01-01'),'%Y-%m-%d'))` works, but only for dates after 1970!

Comment: its since 1970 in W3C http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php "Linux is following the tradition set by Unix of counting time in seconds since its official "birthday," -- called "epoch" in computing terms -- which is Jan. 1, 1970."

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, because [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) cannot handle year 1864:

> The valid range of values is the same as for the TIMESTAMP data type: `'1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000'` UTC to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'` UTC.

It doesn't help either that [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) populates missing data with zeroes:

> Unspecified date or time parts have a value of 0, so incompletely specified values in str produce a result with some or all parts set to 0

```
SELECT 
STR_TO_DATE(1864, '%Y') AS d1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(1864, '%Y')) AS u1,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(1864, '%Y'))) AS f1,
STR_TO_DATE(2017, '%Y') AS d2, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(2017, '%Y')) AS u2,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(2017, '%Y'))) AS f2;
```

```
+------------+------+---------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| d1         | u1   | f1                  | d2         | u2         | f2                  |
+------------+------+---------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1864-00-00 |    0 | 1970-01-01 01:00:00 | 2017-00-00 | 1480460400 | 2016-11-30 00:00:00 |
+------------+------+---------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Whatever you have in mind, you cannot do it with MySQL.

Comment: That's it! All the people of my table where born before 1970! So I'll do it in PHP…

Comment: I found the way!
`SELECT id, DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1-1-',born_date),'%d-%m-%Y'),FROM_UNIXTIME(0))*24*3600 AS born_date_unix`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [Converting a date string which is before 1970 into a timestamp in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788571/converting-a-date-string-which-is-before-1970-into-a-timestamp-in-mysql).

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1-1-',born_date),'%d-%m-%Y'),FROM_UNIXTIME(0))*24*3600 AS born_date_unix
```

And it works!

N.